# Differenital forms locally

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification

Let $X$ be a manifold, for simplicity, 1-dimensional.
I want to understand what this means:

"Locally a differential form $s$ is of the form $f(x)dx$".

As I understand it, differential forms are sections of $T^*X$, thus a map $X \to T^*X$. Taking a local trivialization $U$ of $X$, $s$ can be represented by function $g:U \to X\times \mathbb R$. I think $g$ should be $f$ and the $dx$ simply represents that  $s(x) ( \frac d {dx}) = g(x)$.

On the other hand, if we have a chart $\phi:U\to \mathbb R^n$ with $\phi(x)=0$, we can consider the pull-back $\phi^* s$, a section on $T^*\mathbb R$. On $T^* \mathbb R$, $dx$ is well defined, so $\phi^*(s)$ is of the form $h(x)dx$. Is it then true, that $\phi^*|_U(s)=f(x) dx$?
I think this should be true, because  $\phi^*(s)(0)=s(\phi(x))=s(x)$.

I am not sure. Does this make sense?

---

Edit: So far an answer has been posted, but it doesn't really deal with my thoughts on the topic and what i need clarification of. Any additional answers would be appreciated.

Edit2: Still not answered!

Comment: From my understanding, what you have written is correct :) I don't know though if there is something more to the statement.

Comment: You seem to be using the letter $x$ sometimes as a (point-valued) dummy variable, sometimes to refer to a specific point, and sometimes referring to a scalar field. I very strongly expect that this is the source of your confusion, or at least closely related to it.

Comment: @Hurkyl: This is probably true. Could you take the time and show me how its done properly? Would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you make simple things complicated. In your chart $x: U\to \bf R$ is a function. Thus $dx$, its differential, is a nowhere vanishing differential form, and as your manifold is one dimensional, in this chart every form is proportional to $dx$, ie can be written as $\ f(x) dx$.

Comment: How is the function $x$ defined? How do your $f$ and my $g$, $h$ relate to each other?

Comment: $x$ is coordinate on the manifold.  Fors instance if $U\subset \bf R$ is a subset $x$ is just the inclusion map $x: U\to \bf R$

Comment: What happens if $X\not \subset \mathbb R$?

Comment: then $x$ is the function which defines the chart. In higher dimension a chart is a family of functions $x_1,...,x_n$, but here $n=1$.

Comment: So how is this different from what I wrote after "on the other hand..."?

Comment: Try your formula with the chart $\phi (x)= sin x$ around $0$.

Comment: What is your point?

Comment: hello? Anybody there?

Comment: Will you ever complete your answer?